# org-publish, how to wrap content before first headline in a div

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

If I have the following org file:

```
#+TITLE: Foo & Bar

This is all about foo and bar.

* Foo

...

* Bar

...
```

when I org-publish to html, I'll get something like the following in the content section:

```
...
<div id="content">
  <h1 class="title">Foo & Bar</h1>
  <p>This is all about foo and bar.</p>

  <div id="outline-container-orgXXXXXXX" class="outline-2">
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>

  <div id="outline-container-orgXXXXXXX" class="outline-2">
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
 
</div>
...
```

I'd like

```
<h1 class="title">Foo & Bar</h1>
<p>This is all about foo and bar.</p>
```

i.e. the page title and all content before the first org headline, to also be wrapped in their own div (or similar containing element) within the main div, so that I can target this container specifically with css.

In summary, I would like the following output:

```
...
<div id="content">

  <div class="pre-headlines">
     <h1 class="title">Foo & Bar</h1>
     <p>This is all about foo and bar.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="outline-container-orgXXXXXXX" class="outline-2">
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>

  <div id="outline-container-orgXXXXXXX" class="outline-2">
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
 
</div>
...
```

How would I go about that?

Comment: You say "I'd like ..." but what you show does not agree with what you describe. Can you edit the question and fix that?

Comment: @NickD Thanks - updated to clarify.

Comment: Ah - thanks! I read it wrong the first time. However, I don't think there's an easy way to do what you want: `org-html-template` does not provide any kind of customization that could be used for your purpose, so you'd either have to modify it (which is always problematic) or convince the developers to change it (which imight be no less problematic) or resort to a solution like [filters](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Advanced-Export-Configuration) - maybe.